# How to compute electric field between constantly changing potentials (LFP data)

Tags: electromagnetic, biopotential, eeg

I have a set of LFP (local field potential) data, which is basically the voltage of different points in the brain at different times. I would like to calculate the electric field at these points at all times.
So imagine there are multiple points in space, with constantly changing voltages, and we want to find the electric field profile in this space, across time.

Comment: Sounds like a job for MATLAB.

Comment: What display methods ? http://www.falstad.com/vector3de/